# Data extraction using PHP

Tags: php, html, dom

I am new to PHP and got an assignment seems bit tough. I need to extract the price table from this pagehttp://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen

So far I have done the code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen';

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table[id="priceTable"]') as $data) {
    foreach($data->find('img[width="150"]') as $d) {
        echo $d-> alt. "<br/>";
    }
}
foreach($html->find('div[class="il"]') as $d1) {
    foreach($d1->find('a[rel="nofollow"]') as $d2) {
        echo $d2-> innertext. "<br/>" ;
    }
}
?>
```

It gives me the result but I want shop name and respective price on the same row. It should look like the following:

```
Digitalstreet  € 332,00 

Cameratop      € 332,00
```

But am getting the output as follow:

```
Digitalstreet
Cameratop 
€ 332,00
€ 332,00
```

Can anybody please guide me with this.

Comment: Is the problem just that results are printing on newlines? Remove the <br />

Comment: And how do you getting output currently ?

Comment: @Rikesh now am getting output as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest grabbing the table row for row, and then finding the name and price per row. This way (if something is missing), you are sure the name and price belong together.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen';

$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table[id="priceTable"]') as $data) {
    foreach($html->find('tr') as $rowdata) {
        $name = 'unknown';
        $price = '-';
        foreach($rowdata->find('img[width="150"]') as $namedata) {
            $name = $namedata->alt;
        }
        foreach($rowdata->find('div[class="il"]') as $d) {
            foreach($d1->find('a[rel="nofollow"]') as $d2) {
                $price = $d2->innertext;
            }
        }

        echo $name.' '.$price.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Off course you can add everything to an array instead of echoing it, and the 'default' values can be changed as well according to your needs

Comment: thanks it works but i got the result called unknown...you can check the output here http://test.multicon.in/5.php...the "unknown" is coming from where?!

Comment: oops i got it...but why these blank rows are coming? is there any way to remove those?

Comment: The blank rows come from the "display: none" rows. (class="otherprice otherprice1910429552" and such)

Comment: Got it but is there any way to remove those? AM simply clueless dear:)

Comment: You can check probably check the style attribute (style="display: none") or class name (class="otherprice")

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the first loop loops over the prices and the second loop loops over the names. Assuming both lists are always the same size you can easily store the information in 1 or more arrays and loop over them later.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.kieskeurig.nl/spiegelreflexcamera/nikon/d3200_body/prijzen/bezorgen/1052716#prijzen';

$html = file_get_html($url);

$prices = array();
$names = array();

foreach($html->find('table[id="priceTable"]') as $data) {
    foreach($data->find('img[width="150"]') as $d) {
        $prices[] = $d->alt;
    }
}
foreach($html->find('div[class="il"]') as $d1) {
    foreach($d1->find('a[rel="nofollow"]') as $d2) {
        $names[] = $d->alt;
    }
}

foreach ($names as $key => $name)
{
    echo "$name: " . $prices[$key];
}
```

I can't test if this works, but it should help you to get the right idea.

Comment: while testing the code I got the shop names only no price...the first foreach is for shop name and the second one is for price

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the array looks like.
What you can do is add both the results in an array and loop any one of the array.

For eg:

```
foreach($html->find('table[id="priceTable"]') as $data) {
foreach($data->find('img[width="150"]') as $d){
    $price[] = $d->alt; 
}}
foreach($html->find('div[class="il"]') as $d1){
foreach($d1->find('a[rel="nofollow"]') as $d2){
   $camName[] = $d2->innertext;
}
}
// now loop through the array
echo "<table>"
foreach($camname as $key=>$name){
   echo "<tr><td>{{$name}}</td><td>{{$price[$key]}}</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```